# Maximum number of tables in hbase

Tags: hbase

What is the Maximum number of tables that can be create in HBase?. If i create  tables for saving every hour data. For example 24/8/3013 8:00pm data will be stored in 24_8_2013_8 
Will it affect the HBase performance.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have misunderstood HBase. It was not meant to be used like this. We use HBase when we need to store **really huge** amounts of data. How much data would one acquire in 1 hour? Doesn't sound wise to me.

Better think of a good schema if you really have such requirements. Perhaps one row/hour, or something which suits your use case. But a table for each hour sounds illogical to me.